# Harmonic/Melodic Minor in Keys?

Tags: theory, scales, intervals, key-signatures

How does one find the key to a scale like harmonic minor, or is out of key?

Comment: There are major and minor keys, but not really harmonic or melodic minor keys. They are just minor keys; minor key harmony is somewhat flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For several reasons, all explained in previous answers, there is only one minor *key*. It happens to contain a cocktail of differing notes, the mainstay of that key is the relationship between the root and its third - a **minor third**.

You could read that as 12 minor keys..!  Each with several different optional scales.